# symbolic derivation of a larger function

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, sympy

I want to take the derivative of the following function
        y=(np.log(x))/(1+x),
if I am using sympy, it gives me the following error

```
    from sympy import *
    y1=Derivative((np.log(x))/(1+x), x)
    print y1
```

sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32

Comment: Is that all of your code? Should you not introduce some symbolic variables to sympy (instead on passing undefined python variables like ```x```)?

Comment: @Sanjeev Although it may seem inconvenient, try to [avoid `from ... import *`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad).

Comment: Thanks Sascha and Kazemakase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('x')
x
>>> y1 = diff(log(x)/(1+x))
>>> y1
-log(x)/(x + 1)**2 + 1/(x*(x + 1))
```

- As Sanjeev mentioned in a comment you need to define variables in one way or another.
- np.log in your code would be a function that accepts a numerical value and returns a numerical value; sympy needs to see a function names that it knows in formal terms, such as log
- In this context, you need to use sympy's diff function, rather than Derivative.

Comment: Thanks Bell...Today I went through the complete documentation of sympy from the start and found this thing....thanks a lot!!! and thanks for explaining the np.log thing

Comment: Sanjeev, you're most welcome. I hope you enjoy using sympy as much as I do.